# Fluid sim not colliding with effector

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision

Okay, a pretty simple problem, you can see the fluid sim is passing through my effector. How do I fix that?

So far I've tried flipping the normals, adding and applying a solidify modifier, and decimating the mesh (I read that high polygon density can affect collision). Granted, I could re-topologize the mesh but I'd rather avoid it.

[image]

Comment: I was having the same problem a few weeks back and after a bit of research concluded that fluid sim in blender/mantaflow is very buggy. Sometimes collision works, sometimes it doesn't. I ended up buying the add-on FLIP Fluids and that seems to work a lot better. Note: I am not affiliated with FLIP Fluids.

Comment: Huh, okay, I'll do a little digging on that one and find out if it works.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248062/blender-rig-gen-error-how-can-i-fix

Answer (score 2):

The Collision Effector surface thickness has to be at least 0.5 Thickness, which I have reported as a bug. And I have no idea why the default Sampling Substeps is '0', when I find that is often insufficient.

Comment: I guess the default is 0 simply because it needs less resources than a higher value. And as you said, this is often insufficient, not always. Like many other things fluid simulations are not kind of thing where you get perfect results by keeping the deafult values. I mean, the domain resolution has a default value of 32 - but I never produced anything good with that value. In my opinion it's not even suitable for test bakes since just increasing it to 64 already makes such a big difference... that test bake would give you no real idea what your end result would look like.